# Magento 2.1 Multiple shipping Templates modification

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1.7, cloud

I want to change magento 2.1 multiple shipping option templates. I want to find the location of the templates.

thanks

Comment: Pls check here vendor\magento\module-multishipping\view\frontend\templates\checkout

Answer (score 0):

I have found the module. To show the "Check Out With Multiple Addresses" option I have to move the module to my theme, now its working and have to style the related templates.